# Context free languages

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I have stumbled on this question:

Which of the following languages over the alphabet ${a,b,c,d}$ are context-free and which not ?

a) $L_{1} =  \{wa^{3n+1}b^nw^{R} \mid w\in \{c,d\}^*,\ n>0\}$;

b)  $L_{2} = \{a^{3n+1}wb^nw^{R} \mid w\in \{c,d\}^*,\ n>0\}$.

For a) I think this grammar solves it :

\begin{align*}
 S&\to cMc \mid dMd \mid M\\
 M&\to aN\\
 N&\to aaaTb \mid\varepsilon\\
 T&\to \varepsilon
\end{align*}

b) doesn't look so nice so I think that we might prove it with the pumping lemma,any suggestions what word to pick?

Comment: Pay attention to the difference between {c,d}* and {c,d}. Your proposed solution for (a) restricts w to {c,d}.

Comment: Thank you ,i think i have fixed it any suggestions for the second part?

Comment: Still not quite: now it'll accept {c,d}? = {c,d,ε} rather than {c,d}*.

Comment: Do you have any question about your answer to a)? This site isn't well-suited to "please check my answer" because it's only interesting to you and tends to degenerate into "OK, I fixed that problem. Now is it right?" and Stack Exchange can't handle discussions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the Pumping Lemma for Contextfree languages to prove that the language (b) is not contextfree.
Have a look at the word $a^{3n+1}cdb^ndc$, given n as the Pumping Length.